# See exactly which files each program accesses

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, io

You can easily observe that a program is performing I/O disk operations using a process monitor. Is there an easy way to observe *exactly* what files are being read/written to by each process?

Windows/Linux solutions welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [OpenedFilesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) because I am old. Also check out [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and Resource Monitor (resmon).

Use Windows-R to open the run box. Type `resmon` and hit the Enter-key.

On *nix I'd use [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof).

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about `lsof` - I'll also add that just after reading this answer I found [Handle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) for Windows, which is apparently what Process Explorer builds its GUI on. I generally prefer command-line solutions so I just thought I'd add this too.

Comment: @pigeonburger Ah good point. I forgot about Handle. Russinovich software is always good.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, you would use an app literally called [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), or ProcMon for short. It captures all file and registry access – not just "current" state, but each individual operation.

This type of tool is particularly useful as many files are opened-read-closed quickly, not held open for long durations.

---

The rough Linux equivalent of ProcMon is `strace`. To see all file-related system calls:

```
strace -e file /bin/chmod a+w test.txt
```

Other similar tools are `perf trace` and `ltrace`. BSDs have `ktruss`, I think.

Highly flexible system tracing can be done through `bpftrace` and SystemTap `stap` (both of which are similar to Solaris' `dtrace`). They take a while to learn, though. [Related](https://lwn.net/Articles/852112/).

The Linux *audit* subsystem, with `auditctl`, can be used to track operations on specific files no matter which process they're done by. For example, you can see what's accessing your ~/.ssh/id_rsa private key.

(Similarly, LSMs such as AppArmor can be run in "complain" or "permissive" mode where they only log operations that would be denied, but don't actually deny them.)

The *fanotify* subsystem can be used to get a system-wide firehose feed of all files that are being accessed, e.g. using the `fatrace` tool. (It's similar to inotify, which is per-directory; `inotifywait -rmq ~/foo` would monitor that directory recursively.)